# Regex: to accept numbers for salary field with zero amount as invalid and decimal value to be accepted.ex:0(invalid) 1(valid) 100(valid)1.8(valid)

Tags: regex

Salary Field to accept amount from 1-infinite with decimal value. only 0 is considered as invalid

```
[0-9][1-9.]*[0-9]+[1-9]*

'Salary':['',[Validators.pattern('[0-9][1-9.]*[0-9]+[1-9]*')]]

0 as invaid
1 as valid
100 as valid
99909 as valid
1.2  as valid
111.77700 as valid
```

Comment: what about 0.0 for instance?

and would you want currency signs allowed? how about thousand delimiters ($1,256.00 for instance)

Comment: If a negative lookahead is supported, try `^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` https://regex101.com/r/esOUFT/1

Comment: Is this for Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Validators.pattern` is rather corrupt as it can match any amount of dots in between two digits and the input cannot contain a single digits.

If you allow `0.000` but not just `0`, you may use

```
Validators.pattern('(?!0$)[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?')
```

If you disallow any zero value, including `0.0000`, you need

```
Validators.pattern('(?!0+(?:\\.0+)?$)[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?')
```

or plain

```
Validators.pattern('(?![0.]+$)[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?')
```

Note that Angular will enclose the *string* pattern with anchors automatically: `'(?!0+(?:\\.0+)?$)[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?'` => `/^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/`.

Note you may use a regex literal, too, but you will have to specify the anchors and use single backslashes to define regex escapes:

```
Validators.pattern(/^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5cIevn/1).

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 1+ zeros followed with an optional sequence of a `.` and 1+ digits
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of a `.` and 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the language is JS then this would work:

```
^((\d*[1-9]+\d*(\.\d+)?)|(\d*\.\d*[1-9]+\d*))$
```

You may need to escape the backslashes since it appears you are placing the regex inside a JS string:

```
'Salary':['',[Validators.pattern('^((\\d*[1-9]+\\d*(\\.\\d+)?)|(\\d*\\.\\d*[1-9]+\\d*))$')]]
```

https://regex101.com/r/4uBK9X/3

Comment: It works fine but with operation doesnt seems to work ex:2.3

Comment: @Npsad You should specify your flavor of regex or programming language because **[it clearly works for `2.3`](https://regex101.com/r/4uBK9X/4)**

Comment: @Npsad See my edit, I can only assume that you failed to escape backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the below regex for all the cases you mentioned and more. I hope it helps.

`Validators.pattern('^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9])?')]`

Check out the image.

[Salary regex javascript - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkSM1.png)

Comment: This doesn't match `10.12`

Comment: @Toto You are right. Thanks for pointing it out. I will edit this answer.